# Double Hashing Details

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, hashtable, double-hashing

I currently reviewing for a final exam for my algorithms class and I came across a few questions in the practice test that I was unsure of. Any help would be appreciated!

*Which of the following is not true about probe sequences for an implementation of double hashing?*

A. Two keys could have the same probe sequence

B. All slots in the hash table appear in each probe sequence

C. The elements of a probe sequence are possible keys for the hash table

D. The probe sequence for a key cannot change

I believe A,B,and D are true, so i think C is the correct answer.

---

*The worst case for double hashing is:*

A. All stored keys have the same h1.

B. All stored keys have the same h2.

C. All stored keys have the same h1 and h2.

D. Inserting each key requires probing the slots for all previously inserted keys

I believe that this answer would be C. I'm not entirely sure about this one so an explanation would nice.

Answer (score 0):

1. You say "A,B,and D are true" and think C is false.  While C is obscurely stated, it appears to be true because a probe sequence consists of trying a series of keys.  Look at B more closely, and consider what happens if h2(v) is a divisor of m, the table size.
2. C and D look much alike, as C will cause D.  However, there can be other cases that cause D, so it probably is the answer.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I think for the first problem C is indeed incorrect. The elements of the probe sequence are positions where the item might go in the hash table, not the keys that would be stored in the table itself.